# Data received from web service is not xml

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, web-services, soapui

Using SOAPUI i filled in the relevant information on a XML sheet, the appropriate xml was then received back.

I attempted to replicate this on Visual Studio C#, adding in a service reference, input the exact same data but strangely this is what gets outputted;

> WindowsFormsApplication1.SomeCompanyWebService.TransactionTrialBalance[]

Using this code;

```
AWebService.BIServiceClient Client = new AWebService.BIServiceClient();
Var Response = Client.getTransactions(true, username, Encrypted_password, Period, Year, MethodSignature, Database);
ResultTxtBox.Text = Response.ToString();
```

How would I get XML data?

Comment: You get strongly typed results when you use a Service Reference because the types are created in your project and automatically deserialized. Look at the `Reference.cs` file that was generated when you added the service reference.

Comment: what is it i'm looking for?

Comment: If you hover over `getTransactions` it will show you the return type. But to see where these magic classes live, do a "Show All Files" on the project menu. Then open the Service References folder (might also be Web References), expand what is probably called `AWebService`, drill into the .map file, you should see a Reference.cs file that contains the types that were generated. You don't need to work with the SOAP XML but you could by doing a regular HttpClient call instead of using the client proxy.

Comment: the return value is; `WindowsFormsApplication1.SomeCompanyWebService.TransactionTrialBalance[]` strange... How would i do a httpclient call? could you point me to another thread maybe?

Comment: Just google "c# HttpClient". But why would you want the xml? The service reference makes it much easier because you are just working with .net objects. If, after calling `getTransactions`, you type `Response[0].`, you will see all the xml elements are now just properties on the `TransactionTrialBalance` object.

Comment: if i use httpclient am i still going to be able to use username, password, period, year etc? the literature im looking at doesn't cover this.

Comment: The way you call the service will be very different (and more complicated) but yes, you will have to provide those values as POST data. Unless there is some reason, that I cannot imagine, why you need raw xml, I seriously don't think you want to go there.

Comment: As long as I can get the information from the xml I don't physically need the xml. I can't find any decent guides for httpclient post. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: In that case, don't do it. You already have it built and working.

Comment: its not working, im not able to get the return value in the right format.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what it is you are getting from the call. It is just an array of `TransactionTrialBalance` objects. Parsing SOAP would be much more error prone. I'm telling you it is a mistake, but if you must, see if SOAP UI has a feature to generate code. Most tools like that do. You might be able to generate the HttpClient code, or at least the raw Http request which will help guide you in setting it up yourself.

Comment: Submit as an answer thanks